# CSVデータの内容が一致しているかをテスト

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### 聞きたいことの一行まとめ

CSVデータの取得した内容が正しいかテストをしたい

```
<img title='entries_controller_spec_rb_—_Hairbook.png' alt='entries_controller_spec_rb_—_Hairbook' src='/attachments/02b2bf7f-c207-49b1-aa8d-fcd6a32b81eb' width="1280" data-meta='{"width":1280,"height":254}'>
```

#### 起きている問題（起きている現象の詳細/エラーメッセージ/スクリーンショット）

キャンペーンに参加しているユーザーのCSVデータを取得し、内容が正しいかのテストを実行しようとしてます。
上記スクリーンショットの青枠を配列として取得したいがうまくできない。

#### ソースコード（関連するソースコード/全ソースコード）

```
  describe 'GET /index_csv2' do
    subject { get(admin_campaign_entries_path(campaign, format: :csv)) }

    let(:campaign) { create(:campaign) }

    before do
      create_list(:campaign_entry, 2, campaign: campaign)
      create(:campaign_entry)
    end

    context 'CSVファイルをダウンロードしたとき' do
      it 'CSVデータが正しいこと' do
        subject

        expect(CSV.parse(response.body)).to include "campaign_id_#{campaign.id}_entry_users.csv"
      end
    end
  end
```

- expectの部分は記述している最中です。
- expect箇所であるcsv.parse(response.body)でcreateしたキャンペーンユーザーの情報が取得できてますが配列がうまく取得できない。

#### 問題について自分なりに考えたこと（検索結果/自分なりの原因予想/切り分けた内容）

- https://qiita.com/san_you/items/1fea28b0ebb9c607889b こちらの記事を参考にしようとしたが、配列をうまくとれない。

ruby初心者なのでうまくできず困っています。
何かしらアドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/906ptt6geuw6qc) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: また、「スクリーンショット」と書かれていますが画像が見当たりません。説明に必要なものであれば本文に貼り付けるか、質問文を見直してみて下さい。